# how to use more model in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

As i know in MVC, Model always connect to database, example:

```
class a extends Model {
...
}


class Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $db = new database;
        $db->connect('localhost','root','','example');
    }
}
```

But, in the case i have more Model always run to get config in database. So, when run website will be 2 Model are used.
This equivalent to 2 connect to database so its has effect to system when have many people visit my website (200 request = 400 connect to database)

Comment: Model doesn't **always** connect to database... I think you misunderstood the MVC concept.

Comment: It actually does while every new class extends of Model is being initialized.

Comment: @Hast , then you too are misunderstanding the MVC

Answer (score 0):

### About model

Actually model is not at class in the first place. **Model is a layer**, which contains multitude of objects. The two main groups of class instances in model layer are tasked with one of following responsibilities:

- domain business logic and rules: implemented by domain objects <sup>[(1)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object)</sup>
- data access and persistence: usually implemented as datamappers <sup>[(3)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)</sup>

In code it would looks something similar to this:

```
$user = $factory->buildObject('user');
$mapper = $factory->buildMapper('user');
$user->setId( 42 );
$mapper->fetch($user);
$now = time();
if ( $user->hasStatus( User::STATUS_LOCKED ) && !$user->isBanned( $now ) )
{
   $user->setStatus( User::STATUS_AVAILABLE );
}
$mapper->commit($user);
```

As you might notice, at no point the business object actually interacts with database. Or is even aware of it. It might be that the information is stored in a plain text file, or via remote REST API, or in some noSQL thing. Domain object does not care about that. All the storage is handled by the mapper. The business logic that governs the making of invoice does not depend on location where the information about invoice comes from.

### About connections

Since you are using OOP, you might take advantage of it. Consider this example:

```
class Test
{
    protected $ob = null;
    public function __construct( $ob )
    {
        $this->ob = $ob;
    }
    public function get() 
    {
        var_dump( $this->ob->data );
    }
    public function set( $val )
    {
        $this->ob->data = $val;
    }
}

$object = new stdClass;
$foo = new Test($object);
$bar = new Test($object);

$foo->set('lorem ipsum');
$bar->get();
```

To see executed: http://codepad.org/coCibwyk

You should notice, that both instances of `Test` class are sharing the **same** instance. In your code, you can do the same with instance of [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

And if you are using something similar to first code snipped , then :

```
class Factory
{
    protected $connection = null;
    public function __construct( $connection )
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
    public function buildMapper( $className )
    {
        $className = $className . 'Mapper';
        $instance = new $className ;
        $instance->useConnection( $this->connection );
        return $instance;
    }
    // ... some other code 
}
```

So, when you use `$mapper = $factory->buildMapper('user');` , the method creates an object, which already has a connection.